# How to sign transaction in Tron network with trongrid API 4.7.2 and Python?

Tags: python, transactions, digital-signature, cryptoapi, tron

I have call this post API in Python:

```
url = "https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/createtransaction"
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
}
body = {
    "owner_address": "Txxxxxxx",
    "to_address": "Tyyyyyyyy",
    "amount": 100_000,
    "visible": True
}
```

So in response we get transaction data like this:

```
{'visible': True, 'txID': 'b6b4b95a4864b9a93a9686ae9dccb2e71d415f611da68d80ec75e3e366488s77', 'raw_data': {'contract': [{'parameter': {'value': {'amount': 100000, 'owner_address': 'Txxxxxxx', 'to_address': 'Tyyyyyyyy'}, 'type_url': 'type.googleapis.com/protocol.TransferContract'}, 'type': 'TransferContract'}], 'ref_block_bytes': '2c65', 'ref_block_hash': '3d73328b7ccf78s3', 'expiration': 1693055346000, 'timestamp': 1693055288583}, 'raw_data_hex': '0a022c6522083d73328b7cxxxxx'}
```

So we can use second API

> https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/gettransactionsign

To sign transaction with private key, But in 2023 this API depricated and not supported anymore.

So i need to know what is the best alternative for this API?
Run new **node** on my own server? If this is best way, tell me how?
Do it **offline**? Is it possible and how?
Or any suggestion.

Comment: This methos in tronweb static signString(message, privateKey, useTronHeader = true) sign a transaction but can not find it for Python